# How to add a window to a specific node in Write window of CANoe

Tags: capl, canoe

How can I a write window to a specific node in CANoe configuration? I can see a write window for node SSC EV but I wanted to add another one more for a node.

[image]

Comment: There is no image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all take a look in CANoe manual

CANoe» Analysis Windows » Write Window

here you will find important note about limitations for lines in Write-Window.
Thereafter you can find short explanation about standard pages in Write-Window here:

Write Window » Views

There is also a link to CAPL function *writeCreate()* which can be used to create new page. The return value of this function shall be used as parameter for function *writeConfigure()* to write onto created page. See also example for this functions in help.